# Get all Invocation expression names in a MethodDeclaration body

Tags: c#, roslyn, code-analysis

I am trying to find all instances of `Update()` method declarations and then checking its body's invocation expression identifier tokens to see if it's called `GetComponent`.

How would I go about doing this? I can find the method declaration of `Update` but don't know how to proceed further...

Initializing the analysis

```cs
public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
{
    context.EnableConcurrentExecution();
    context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
    context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(Analyze, SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration);
}
```

Getting the method declaration name and calling the diagnostic

```cs
private static void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    if (context.Node is not MethodDeclarationSyntax method)
        return;
    var symbolname = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(method);
    var node = context.Node;
    if (symbolname.Name != "Update")
        return;
    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, node.GetLocation()));
}
```

How the Syntax tree looks: I need to get to `MethodDeclaration` -> `Block` -> `ExpressionStatement` -> `InvocationExpression` -> `IdentifierToken`

[image: Syntax Tree]

Update:
By working from the invocation expression first and going up it was an easier task, here is the complete code of what I wanted to achieve:

```
        private static void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
        var name = invocation.GetMethodNameSyntax();
        if (name == null)
            return;
        if (name.Identifier.Text != "GetComponent")
            return;
        var parent = invocation.Expression.FirstAncestorOrSelf<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
        var classDeclaration = parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
        if (classDeclaration == null)
            return;
        var symbolname = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(parent);
        if (symbolname.Name != "Update" )
            return;
        context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.GetLocation()));

    }
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the recent update solves your problem? If so, would you mind writing up an answer?

Answer (score 2):

Easier to achieve my solution by working bottom-up.
Get all the invocations - > check if it's your desired invocation - > get the invocations expression parent - > see if the method name is correct and then return the diagnostic. Missing a few null checks, but it's good enough.

```
private static void Analyze(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
{
    var invocation = (InvocationExpressionSyntax)context.Node;
    var name = invocation.GetMethodNameSyntax();
    if (name == null)
        return;
    if (name.Identifier.Text != "GetComponent")
        return;
    var parent = invocation.Expression.FirstAncestorOrSelf<MethodDeclarationSyntax>();
    var classDeclaration = parent.FirstAncestorOrSelf<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
    if (classDeclaration == null)
        return;
    var symbolname = context.SemanticModel.GetDeclaredSymbol(parent);
    if (symbolname.Name != "Update" )
        return;
    context.ReportDiagnostic(Diagnostic.Create(Rule, invocation.GetLocation()));

}
```